# Complex Query Optimization

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

Running Postres 7.4 (yep upgrading)

This is a view query and it's used a lot but takes longer than I would like. Any Optimization Suggestions? Any field with a Id in the name is indexed

```
SELECT  
db_tbl_1.field_id, s."Field ID" AS foreign_field_id,
s."Field Name" AS field_name,
CASE    
    WHEN SUBSTRING(s."Field ID" FROM 0 FOR 3) = '01' THEN 'Field Label 1'
    WHEN SUBSTRING(s."Field ID" FROM 0 FOR 4) = '321' THEN 'Field Label 1' 
    WHEN SUBSTRING(s."Field ID" FROM 0 FOR 5) = '1234' THEN 'Field Label 1'
    WHEN SUBSTRING(s."Field ID" FROM 0 FOR 6) = '55555' THEN 'Field Label 1'    
    WHEN SUBSTRING(s."Field ID" FROM 0 FOR 3) = '76' THEN 'Field Label 2' 
END AS new_field, s.field_1,
db_tbl_2.field_2, db_tbl_1.field_2_a, 
db_tbl_1.field_3, db_tbl_1.field_4,
db_tbl_1.field_5, db_tbl_1.field_6, db_tbl_1.field_date_1,
db_tbl_1.field_7, db_tbl_2.field_8 AS new_field_name,
s."Field Date" AS field_date, db_tbl_1.created_date,
CASE
    WHEN (((DATE_TRUNC('month', "Field Date") + INTERVAL '2 MONTH') - "Field Date" > 60) AND 
         ((DATE_TRUNC('month', "Field Date") + INTERVAL '2 MONTH') - "Field Date" <= 92))
    THEN (DATE_TRUNC('month', "Field Date") + INTERVAL '2 MONTH')
    -- the most days in a three month span can be 92
    ELSE (DATE_TRUNC('month', "Field Date") + INTERVAL '3 MONTH')
END AS next_date
FROM db_schema_1.db_tbl_1, db_schema_1.db_tbl_2, "Table S" AS s
WHERE db_tbl_1.program_level_id = db_tbl_2.id
AND db_tbl_1.field_id = s."Another ID"
AND (CASE   
    WHEN SUBSTRING(s."Field ID" FROM 0 FOR 3) = '01' THEN 1
    WHEN SUBSTRING(s."Field ID" FROM 0 FOR 4) = '321' THEN 1 
    WHEN SUBSTRING(s."Field ID" FROM 0 FOR 5) = '1234' THEN 1
    WHEN SUBSTRING(s."Field ID" FROM 0 FOR 6) = '55555' THEN 1  
    WHEN SUBSTRING(s."Field ID" FROM 0 FOR 3) = '76' THEN 1
    ELSE 0 
END) = 1
```

Comment: Not posting as an answer since I don't know Postgres, but in SQL Server I avoid `SUBSTRING` and instead use `LEFT` in scenarios like this, since `LEFT` will use the index and `SUBSTRING` will not.  To get that `SUBSTRING` it is likely evaluating every row and just doing a table scan.

Comment: Hmm not finding the documentation for LEFT() with Postgres 7.4, or any Postgres version. Could you provide a reference?

Comment: It's apparently not in there!  Told you I didn't know Postgres :)

Comment: Do you have indexes, what are possible values in s."Field ID" ?

Comment: yes anything with the label Id is an index, "Field ID" is 20 chracter long varchar

Comment: There is functional indexes but I'm not sure in which versions of PostgreSQL. They are good for last condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the last statement, where you are using the case statement because the query will evaluate all of them. and then check if is equals to 1,  you should try and "OR" statement, because if one is correct, it will not evaluate the other alternatives. It should help you a bit. Something like this.

```
AND ( SUBSTRING(s."Field ID" FROM 0 FOR 3) = '01' OR
    SUBSTRING(s."Field ID" FROM 0 FOR 4) = '321' OR
    SUBSTRING(s."Field ID" FROM 0 FOR 5) = '1234' OR
    SUBSTRING(s."Field ID" FROM 0 FOR 6) = '55555' OR
    SUBSTRING(s."Field ID" FROM 0 FOR 3) = '76'
)
```

Comment: don't know postgres sql, but if there is an IN statement you could change it SUBSTRING(s."Field ID" FROM 0 FOR 3) IN ('01', '76'), should help a little bit more as well

Comment: well the IN does work with the two digit but there is no/if any optimization or the OR condition